# How to call the string[] from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have the following function in C#.

```
public static string[] StringValue()
{
       .....
       return MyString;
}
```

I am trying to call the function in C++ using,

```
array<String^>^ MyString;
MyString = MyClass.StringValue();   

for(int iter=0; iter < MyString->Length; iter++)
{       
    printf("%s", MyString[iter]);       
}
```

The Value of `MyString[iter]` is not coming properly. It is proper in C# while debugging. The Length of `MyString` is coming proper but not the value.

Comment: Also, there is a `for each` syntax in C++/cli. And don't mix C++ or C calls without marshaling the data-type to the correct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%s", MyString[iter]);
```

This expects a pointer to null-terminated array of `char`. And `MyString[iter]` sure is not that. Since you have a managed string, in a C++/CLI assembly, you can output it like this:

```
Console::WriteLine(MyString[iter]);
```

Comment: This code results me in string; but the value differs. what could be the reason ?

Comment: Impossible to tell from here without details

Comment: I have solved this issue, by changing the encoding, the issue was with Encoding format. :)

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a C function and, unless really needed, is very out of place in C++/CLI code.

```
auto myStrings = MyClass::StringValues();
for each (auto s in myStrings) {
    Console::WriteLine(s);
}
```

Strings can be very difficult to work with but .NET makes it easier. If you can, keep them in .NET. Otherwise, you'll have to deal with different character sets, encodings, data structures, memory allocation and ownership transfer conventions.

Comment: This code is printing some values, but which is not the actual value. Does it because of any encoding issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
printf("%s", MyString[iter]);
```

try to use

```
for ( int i = 0; i < MyString[iter].Length; i++ )   
   std::wcout << MyString[iter][i];
```

EDIT: You could use

```
System::Console::WriteLine( MyString[iter] );
```

Comment: `error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` I got for this line.. :(

Comment: @Dineshkumar Ponnusamy Try to use System::Console::WriteLine( MyString[iter] );